# How to update an ID number of a user without duplicating in database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have this Update method, can you please correct my sql statement if its correct or not? Because I tried updating an IDnumber and change it to an existing IDnumber in my database, it just updates anyway without even trying to error trap it.

My code now is :

```
    public void Update()
    {
        sc.Open();

        try
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE TableVotersInfo SET Education=@ed, idnum=@idnum, FirstName=@firstname, MiddleName=@middlename, LastName=@lastname, SchoolYear=@schoolyear, ControlNum=@controlnum WHERE id=@id
                                    SELECT @ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum
                                    WHERE @id NOT IN (SELECT idNum FROM TableVotersInfo);", sc))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
                    FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
                    FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Updated!");
                    FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
                    FAddVoters._checkID = "0";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Can you please tell me where and what am I doing wrong ?

**(EDIT)**

[image: Primary Key]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1383507_313879078755024_1274582164_n.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by "it just updates without error trap"?

Comment: even though it says "ID number already exist!", it updates anyway, then there are duplicate IDs in my database. it does not follow my first condition.

Comment: I'd advise you to open up SQL Studio and make sure that the query is performing as intended there before putting it into C# code where it becomes harder to debug.

Comment: Looks like it is behaving correctly: the UPDATE statement is updating the existing code and then selecting data back. Your .Read() has rows of data so you get the "ID number exists" message. What are you expecting to happen - what isd is being duplicated - IDNUM?

Comment: yes IDnum is being duplicated. I tried updating an IDnum that has been already used. then, even though it says "ID number already exist!", the IDnum is changed to the existing IDnum anyways. so it's duplicated.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to happen. Do you want the update to fail if the value you pass in the `@idnum` parameter already exists in the table? More generally, is the SQL statement not doing what you want, or is your C# code not doing what you want?

Comment: @JimMischel yes that's right. I want the update to fail if the vaule in my `@idnum` parameter already exists in my table. I think both is not doing what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` command won't return any records for you to `Read`, the `ExecuteReader` is used only for `SELECT` command. You can just update normally with `ExecuteNonQuery` and use `try-catch` to know if there is something wrong:

```
public void Update()
{
    sc.Open();
    try {
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE TableVotersInfo SET Education=@ed, idnum=@idnum, FirstName=@firstname, MiddleName=@middlename, LastName=@lastname, SchoolYear=@schoolyear, ControlNum=@controlnum WHERE id=@id
                                SELECT @ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum
                                WHERE @id NOT IN (SELECT idNum FROM TableVotersInfo);", sc))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// <-- this is what you want
            MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Updated!");
            FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
            FAddVoters._checkID = "0";
        }
    } catch (SqlException ex) {
        if(ex.Number == 2627)//duplicated primary key 
        {
           MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
           FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
           FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
        } else {
           MessageBox.Show("There was some error while attempting to update!\nTry again later.");
        }
    }
    finally {
        sc.Close();
    }
}
```

### **UPDATE**

In case you can't make the `idnum` as primary key (because of some designing reason), you have to execute some query to check the existence like this:

```
public bool ExistsKey(string keyField, string table, string value, SqlConnection con){      
  try {
   if(con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
   using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                             table, keyField, value), con)){
     var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
     return result != null && (int)result == 1;
   }
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
  finally {
    con.Close();
  }      
}
//Then use that method in your code like this:

if(ExistsKey("idnum", "TableVotersInfo", _idnum.ToString(), sc)){
  MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
  FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
  FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
} else {
  //perform your update here ...
}
```

Comment: it still continue on updating even though i inputted an existing `idnum`. I want it to check for same `idnum` before storing to database. if it has the same `idnum` then it shouldn't be updated, but if it has none then it could be updated.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete it's because **there was not any exception**, and that means **you designed your table wrong**, your table doesn't have any **primary key** column. Be sure that you see some **yellow key** at some row in the **design view**, take some snap shot to prove that your table has the correct primary key column.

Comment: ahh, sorry my primary key is `id` and my `idnum` is different from my `id`.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I can see the `idnum` is not primary key. If you can't make it `primary key`, you may have to execute some query before updating to know if the `idnum` is already existing.

Comment: I made it as `identity` already. Now, everytime i hit the button update it goes to `else` condition of 'SqlException`.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete no, making it `identity` won't allow you to update it as you want (because it's filled automatically and updating it will always throw exception). See my update for another solution.

Comment: where do I put the public bool? coz it has errors when i put it in my codes.

Comment: there are some errors in the public bool existskey. one is the `var result = com.ExecuteScalar;` the error is `Invalid initializer member declarator.`

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I missed a `)` after the `...table, keyField, value), con)`.